# MonoTouch UIButton Gradient Covers Title

Tags: xamarin.ios, uibutton, xamarin

I have a similar problem to this post ([UIButton: Add gradient layer and title is not shown anymore - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780310/uibutton-add-gradient-layer-and-title-is-not-shown-anymore-how-to-fix)) but his solution did not work for me.  First things first, I'm somewhat new to MonoTouch, but have never gone as far as customizing the out of the box controls.

I am trying to add a gradient to my button, but when I do so, the gradient looks exactly as I want, but the text is covered (I set the opacity of my gradient to .5 to test).  I have a storyboard in which I have visually designed the interface, but want to tweak a few things.

Here is my code:

```
var gradient = new CAGradientLayer();
gradient.Frame = getStartedButton.Layer.Bounds;
gradient.Colors = new MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor[]
{
    UIColor.FromRGB (23, 55, 94).CGColor,
    UIColor.FromRGB (33, 81, 141).CGColor
};

getStartedButton.Layer.AddSublayer(gradient);
getStartedButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
getStartedButton.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
getStartedButton.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;

getStartedButton.VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center;
getStartedButton.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 12);
getStartedButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);

getStartedButton.SetTitle("Get Started", UIControlState.Normal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassing, but it was simply a matter of changing the type of button to custom in XCode.