# The problem with gradiant layer in the UIBUTTON in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, core-graphics, swift5

now I am  designing  button with gradient layer like show in the  picture
I have two problems

1- when I add gradient layer to the button the text disappear like show in the last figure

2- The gradient layer I have created does not like the design the left side of the color in the real design alpha less than right ,I have added the right code but does not show what I want

-This parameters  what I am using

[image]

```
   @IBDesignable
class buttonGeneralDesign: UIButton {
private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!
          @IBInspectable
          var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0{
              didSet{
                  self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
                self.clipsToBounds = false
              }
          }
          
          @IBInspectable
          var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {
              didSet {
                  self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
              }
          }
          @IBInspectable
          var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
              didSet {
                  self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
              }
          }
          @IBInspectable
           var shadowColor: UIColor = .clear {
               didSet {
                   self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
               }
           }
          @IBInspectable
           var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
               didSet{
                   self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
               }
           }
          
          @IBInspectable
          var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.0 {
              didSet{
                  self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
              }
          }
          
          @IBInspectable
            var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize.zero{
                didSet{
                    self.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
                }
            }
  
  
 
  @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = .red {
      didSet {
          setNeedsLayout()
      }
  }
  
  @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = .yellow {
      didSet {
          setNeedsLayout()
      }
  }

  
  @IBInspectable var startPointX: CGFloat = 0 {
      didSet {
          setNeedsLayout()
      }
  }
  
  @IBInspectable var startPointY: CGFloat = 0.5 {
      didSet {
          setNeedsLayout()
      }
  }
  
  @IBInspectable var endPointX: CGFloat = 1 {
      didSet {
          setNeedsLayout()
      }
  }
  
  @IBInspectable var endPointY: CGFloat = 0.5 {
      didSet {
          setNeedsLayout()
      }
  }
  
//  override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
//      return CAGradientLayer.self
//  }
  
  override func layoutSubviews() {
      self.gradientLayer =  CAGradientLayer()
      self.gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
      self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: startPointX, y: startPointY)
     self.gradientLayer.locations = [0,1]
      self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: endPointX, y: endPointY)
    self.gradientLayer.position = self.center

      self.layer.insertSublayer( self.gradientLayer, at: 0)
    
  }
  
  
  
    }
```

-This is the real design

[image]

This is output of the app

[image]

Comment: `self.gradientLayer.position = self.center` You should instead do `self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds` I think that's more the issue.

Comment: thank you very much second problem has been solved.What about text why is not appear ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780310/uibutton-add-gradient-layer-and-title-is-not-shown-anymore-how-to-fix Apparently, you need to insert eh sublayer comparing the title else it will be above.

Comment: after I have added  self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds to the code , when I press the button the color turns to white @Larme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **First:** don't insert layer in `layoutSubview` because it calls many
   times
2. **Second:** Use below or above when inserting layer
3. **Third:** use `self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds` instead of `self.gradientLayer.position = self.center`

   .

   ```
   import UIKit
    @IBDesignable
   class buttonGeneralDesign: UIButton {
   private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!
             @IBInspectable
             var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0{
                 didSet{
                     self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
                   self.clipsToBounds = false
                 }
             }

             @IBInspectable
             var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {
                 didSet {
                     self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
                 }
             }
             @IBInspectable
             var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
                 didSet {
                     self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
                 }
             }
             @IBInspectable
              var shadowColor: UIColor = .clear {
                  didSet {
                      self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
                  }
              }
             @IBInspectable
              var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
                  didSet{
                      self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
                  }
              }

             @IBInspectable
             var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.0 {
                 didSet{
                     self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
                 }
             }

             @IBInspectable
               var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize.zero{
                   didSet{
                       self.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
                   }
               }



     @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = .red {
         didSet {
             setNeedsLayout()
         }
     }

     @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = .yellow {
         didSet {
             setNeedsLayout()
         }
     }


     @IBInspectable var startPointX: CGFloat = 0 {
         didSet {
             setNeedsLayout()
         }
     }

     @IBInspectable var startPointY: CGFloat = 0.5 {
         didSet {
             setNeedsLayout()
         }
     }

     @IBInspectable var endPointX: CGFloat = 1 {
         didSet {
             setNeedsLayout()
         }
     }

     @IBInspectable var endPointY: CGFloat = 0.5 {
         didSet {
             setNeedsLayout()
         }
     }

       override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: .zero)
           commonInit()
       }

       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: coder)
           commonInit()
       }

       func commonInit(){
           self.gradientLayer =  CAGradientLayer()
           self.gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
          self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: startPointX, y: startPointY)
          self.gradientLayer.locations = [0,1]
          self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: endPointX, y: endPointY)
          self.layer.insertSublayer( self.gradientLayer, below: self.titleLabel?.layer)
       }

     override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

     }



       }
   ```

Comment: `layoutSubviews` you might need only setting the frame, no need for the colors, locations, start and endPoint to set them each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
func SetupGradientLeft2Right() {
    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor,UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```